# UI for selecting custom colors in an app

Tags: android, ios, app

What is the standard color picker component for selecting and changing colors in an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS app you could use following library :-

- [colorpicker](https://github.com/kartech/colorpicker)
- [InfColorPicker](https://github.com/InfinitApps/InfColorPicker)
- [NKO-Color-Picker-View-iOS](https://github.com/FWCarlos/NKO-Color-Picker-View-iOS)

And many more you could find out on github or google itself, and difference could be the feature they provide so it depend's on what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several color picker libraries for Android.  For example:

[Android Color Picker](https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/)

[ColorPickerView](https://code.google.com/p/color-picker-view/)

They provide familiar, idiomatic interfaces for picking colors.  Using one of these libraries, or something similar, would make the most sense.